# How to root Lenovo B (A016a40)?

Tags: rooting, lenovo

I am trying to root my Lenovo B (A2016a40), but I absolutely cannot find a working method. Here are some specs of my phone as a screenshot:

[image]

I have tried several apps (desktop and Android) such as KingoRoot, Framaroot, and so on, but nothing has worked so far. I have found this way:
[Kingo Root - How to Get Root Access on Android 6.0/6.0.1 Marshmallow devices with KingoRoot](https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-root-android-6.0-marshmallow.htm) but I am not sure if this can be applied to my phone or not and I am scared to brick it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Look here (translation using Google works fine): http://lenovo-forums.ru/topic/21625-lenovo-a2016a40-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-twrp-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8/ Please note that there are different builds (and the link only works for an early build).

Comment: @Bob Ah right I had come across that forum post before, but unfortunately it's in Russian and I don't speak any Russian, so I did not want to do something on a Google Translation. Besides, how would I know whether that would work for my phone, with my firmware and stuff? If there is someone who figured out how to root it, why can none of the Kingoroot, Framaroot or whatever-root-apps do it also and make sure it would work before I brick my phone? Long story short, I didn't dare to do it.

Comment: Similar series here :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aLpy1qbn8s Is on spanish but is comprehensible

Comment: Regarding rooting apps: [Why are the rooting apps not working anymore?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205706/44325)

Answer (score -1):

I am recommending you to use KingoRoot application because this app is very great for rooting devices and it won't put your device in brick. If this app failed during root, it automatically closes itself and notified you.
In the end, it is your decision and you are responsible for your work.

Comment: Yeah i keep trying KingoRoot but according to the site it doesn't support Marshmallow (yet). I have good experiences with KingoRoot, because I rooted my wife's Samsung Galaxy Note 3 with it. I just wonder, how come until now none of those rooting apps support Marshmallow. Or is it something phone specific? I mean if it's personal towards my Lenovo B?

Comment: OP has mentioned "KingoRoot" on the question and it failed though.